# titlesec tikz twocolumn odd behavior

Tags: tikz-pgf, two-column, titlesec, incompatibility

In the code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1ex}{}[:]

\begin{document}
    \section{Section}

\subsection{First subection}

\lipsum[1-3]

\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```

the second subsection is pushed to the next page.  This does not happen when `tikz` isn't loaded or when the subsection isn't redefined.  What causes this?

It's not a big deal since this feature disappears once one adds some text to the second subsection, but I can imagine that there are other undesirable side effects....

Comment: Suggest: remove `tikz` and replace by `\makeatletter
\input pgfutil-common.tex
\input pgfutil-latex.def
\makeatother` for a more minimal example.

Comment: If you look at `pgfutil-latex.def`, you may be surprised it doesn't cause greater oddities more frequently :-).